# How to configure Automapper to initialize every member in destination?

Tags: c#, automapper

We need that if the member doesn't exist on source but it exists in the destination, to have the destination member initialized. Currently we get nulls unless we manually initialize every single of the 15 members with:

```
List<string> Property = new List<string>();
```

This is our service

```
    public MappingService()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Car, Bike>();
        });

        _mapper = config.CreateMapper();
    }

    public Bike MapToBike(Car car)
    {
        return _mapper.Map<Car, Bike >(car);
    }
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what do you want to achieve. Maybe .ForMember or .AfterMap will help you

Comment: Your question doesn't include enough information for anyone to be able to provide any help.

Comment: @Neistow We want to have every destination member with values from the origin or at least initialized to its default, not null. So for the List example to have a List initialized with 0 elements, not a null List.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ I added more info, please let me know if more info is necessary to be helped with this.

Comment: The default value for List is null, not empty list. Do you want only list properties to be treated this way, meaning initialized with empty list?

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ  yes. It happens with all reference types, like Lists and strings. The strings are being nullified even if they were initialized to string.Empty.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should not rely on AutoMapper initializing your collections. Having null as property value is a valid case after all.
That said, although there is no standard way to do that, you can devise something that might work. For example, as mentioned, you can use `.AfterMap()` to populate all null collections with empty ones. Here is an extension method to do so:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Populates all properties of standard collection types with empty collections
/// </summary>
public static IMappingExpression<TSrc, TDest> InitializeNullCollectionProps<TSrc, TDest>(this IMappingExpression<TSrc, TDest> map)
{
    return map.AfterMap((src, dest) =>
    {
        var destType = typeof(TDest);

        // find all applicable properties
        var collectionProps = destType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public)
            .Where(propInfo =>
            {
                if (!propInfo.CanRead)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                // check if there is public setter 
                if (propInfo.GetSetMethod() == null)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                
                var propertyType = propInfo.PropertyType;
                // it can be Array, List, HashSet, ObservableCollection, etc
                var isCollection = !propertyType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IList));
                if (!isCollection)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                var haveParameterlessCtor =
                    propertyType.GetConstructors().Any(ctr => !ctr.GetParameters().Any());
                if (!haveParameterlessCtor)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            })
            .ToList();
        
        // assign empty collections to applicable properties
        foreach (var propInfo in collectionProps)
        {
            var value = propInfo.GetValue(dest);
            if (value == null)
            {
                propInfo.SetValue(dest, Activator.CreateInstance(propInfo.GetType()));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

It's usage will simply be:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<Src,Dest>()
   // some mappings
   .InitializeNullCollectionProps()
   // some mappings
```

But I don't think there is a way to accurately determine if the member was already mapped to null from source, so it will have empty collection value anyway.

Comment: The OP mentioned "if the member doesn't exist in the src, but exists in the destination..", but you didn't address that. Once you do, your concern in the last paragraph won't be a concern anymore. Isn't that right?

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ yes, as I mentioned there is no easy way to know whether a property was mapped. It's simple for auto-mapped members with the same names, but there are a lot of ways to map destination values differently (value resolvers, differently named src prop, etc). It isn't safe to just check src property names.

Comment: Why not? Checking if a property exists in dest and not in src seems like a valid way to determine the property is not going to be auto mapped.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ Consider mapping: `.ForMember(dest => dest.Foo, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.Bar))`. If `src.Bar` is null, should `dest.Bar` be initialized?
I assumed that ultimately OP just wanted all collections to be activated rather than accurate null-collection mapping. Otherwise, it would be non-trivial to find real value source to make sure it shouldn't be null on dest. And frankly, I don't think this code will be very useful.